# Android Studio 2.0 QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread on OSX

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

On late 2013 iMac running OSX 10.11 trying to run the a simulator throws the `QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread` error. I have tried re-installing the Intel HAXM drivers to no avail. Any help is much appreciated.

```
 /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_9_API_22
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 192MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
Creating filesystem with parameters:
   Size: 69206016
   Block size: 4096
   Blocks per group: 32768
   Inodes per group: 4224
   Inode size: 256
   Journal blocks: 1024
   Label: 
   Blocks: 16896
   Block groups: 1
   Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

Note: Android 2.1.2 fixes this issue for me.

Comment: For those affected by this bug please upvote (star) this ticket  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206383

Comment: I do not use OS X and so I cannot suggest a workaround, other than to use a different OS, like Linux. :-) That being said, your problem is unlikely to be related to HAXM, but rather the `qemu` environment used for the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Two unsatisfactory workarounds:

- Suppress the emulator GUI:
  emulator -no-window ....
  Aps will run on the emulator but you can only see them in the debugger, not on the display
- Suppress use of the GPU:
  emulator -gpu off ....
  Aps will run sucessfully, with full UI, but very slowly